# Suppose $x_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive reals with $\sum x_n$ converges, must $(n\log n)x_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

We are able to show, using the Cauchy criterion (using sum from $n$ to $2n$) that $nx_n \to 0$ Explicitly this is $0<nx_{2n}<\displaystyle \sum_{i=n}^{2n}x_n$ and the result follows from squeeze rule. My question is can we do better?

Intuitively, it feels like we should since $\frac{n\log n}{n^k} \to 0$ for $k>1$. Unfortunately, I am struggling to prove this, Any **hints** would be much appreciated.

One idea I had was to say that if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=N}^{n} x_i > \sum_{i=N}^{n} \frac{1}{n^k}$ for $k>1$ and for all sufficiently large $n$ then we could somehow compare it to the harmonic series. Could we not say the tail of the series could be made as large as we want this way and so divergence would be inevitable?

Comment: @Winther "decreasing"

Comment: How about $x_n = \frac{1}{n \log n}$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Doesn't converge, use Cauchy Condensation test @sudeep5221

Comment: Yeah my bad I forgot that condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N_k = 2^{k^2}$ and define $(x_n)$ by $x_1 = 1$ and $x_n = \frac{1}{N_k \log N_k}$ if $N_{k-1} < n \leq N_k$ and $k \geq 1$. Then $(x_n)$ is positive and (weakly) decreasing. Also,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n
= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{N_k - N_{k-1}}{N_k \log N_k}
\leq 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2\log 2}
< \infty. $$

On the other hand, $(n \log n) x_n = 1$ for infinitely many $n$, and so, it does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Note: the sequence thus defined is only non-increading, not *decreasing*. However, "perturbing" it by a ridiculously negligible amount (e.g., $y_i = x_i + 1/2^i$) will fix that, leaving the argument intact.

Comment: Wow! That's quite impressive, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This holds when additionally $nx_n$ **decreases** to $0$.

Indeed let us state the following lemma: if $(b_n)$ is a sequence that decreases to $0$, $\sum_n \frac{b_n}{n} <\infty \implies b_n=o\left( \frac 1{\log n}\right)$.

To prove the lemma, note that by condensation, $\sum_n b_{2^n}$ converges, hence $b_{2^n}=o\left(\frac 1n\right)$ and $b_n=o\left( \frac 1{\log n}\right)$.

Applying the lemma with $b_n = nx_n$ yields the claim.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: show that the series
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n (\ln n)(\ln \ln n)}$$
is divergent. From this it follows that $x_n$ must decrease faster, if $\sum_n x_n$ is to be convergent.

Comment: That... is not a proof, nor an argument that actually works.

Comment: I said it's a hint.

Comment: Then it's a hint that doesn't work.

Comment: Considering sequences of that form cannot be made to work I dont think

Comment: Except the statement isn't true, so the hint doesn't do any good.